# "Show all" by default in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

My question is directly related to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76634/is-there-a-way-to-make-finder-always-expand-to-show-all-by-default-in-icon-vi) question in LION version.

I use Icon view in Finder and I want to get rid of "Show all" behaviour, i.e. I want all files to be shown by default.

Now, I am on Mavs, but still have no way to expand all the items by default in icon view.

Can we view all files by default in icon view in OS X?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the folder and press ⌘J, then set Arrange By to None. This will still sort using whatever you have chosen for Sort By. Click Use as Defaults to use this option as default and remove the .DS_Store from any folder that you wish to inherit these defaults.

Comment: I am sorry, but I try to not mess all the icons... :(